# Creating an interactive grid for a puzzle game

Tags: .net, grid, puzzle

I am trying to make a slitherlink game, and am not too sure how to approach creating the game, more specifically the grid structure on which the puzzle will be played on.

This is what a empty and completed slitherlink grid would look like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1kXn.gif]

The numbers in the squares are sort of clues and the areas between the dots need to be clickable:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMwiv.gif]

I would like to create the game in VB .NET. What data structures should I try to use, and would it be beneficial using any frameworks such as XNA?

Answer (score 1):

Hey Noupoi and welcome to gamedev.stackexchange!
Starting with your first question:

As your game board will be a nice rectangular thingy you can use an array.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx

To represend the game board you may want to create your own data structure which contains the folowing informations:

- The number of the field
- Information about the walls

As an alternative you can use an int array for the numbers and another array for the walls and binary code the walls.

As for XNA it will help you with some higher MAth  (which I assume you dont need) and with the rendering part. It is basicly a framework which helps you at working with directX, so if you want to extend your game in this direction (maybe use 2D graphics instead of plain numbers) it may get very handy. 
For me the structure used by XNA also feels very confortable so I use it even in some non directly gaming related project. But this is of course a personal opinion.

I hope this helps a bit!

Regards

floAr

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How should I go about creating the interface for the user to do the puzzle on. The boards for slitherlink can be of varying sizes, and ideally, I would like the user to be able to click on the spaces between the dots to make their input.

Comment: You can catch the input with simple math. Just get the coordinates the user clicket on and then chech between which two fileds it is. this should be fairly easy using your tilesize and some if statements.